# Segmentation fault when trying to load RoboDK

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, software-installation

I've been trying to install RoboDK on 3 different Ubuntu Machines. Two of them were running 14.04 and one of them is running 16.04. All three of them could install successfully but none of them would launch the actual program.

The error that I get is always:

```
./start-robodk.sh: line 5: 12436 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./RoboDK
```

It's very weird because I know that I am doing something wrong since I have tried it on 3 separate machines and all of them come up with this error.

I would really appreciate if someone has anything information at all about this matter.

Thanks very much!

Comment: How'd you install it? Looks like you're running a script instead of an installed binary (or you shouldn't need the leading `./`). Isn't there a package in Ubuntu's repos, or at least a PPA?

Comment: There is a script named "install.sh".As far as I know, the archive contains binaries so there is an executable in the /bin folder of where I extracted it to. I have already made the program executable and then running ./RoboDK straight from the /bin folder but it still gives me the same error. The start-robodk.sh script just goes into the bin folder and tries to execute RoboDK.

Comment: If the script isn't causing the segfault, then it must be the binaries. Are they specifically for your version of Ubuntu? Right architecture? Missing dependencies? That's most of the stuff that software repositories & PPA's try to take care of. Or maybe it's just a bug in the program